how to change the default container runtime from runc to crun on docker engine

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: /usr/bin/crun did not terminate successfully: exit status 255: : unknown.
ERRO[0006] error waiting for container: context canceled

i am using ubuntu 22.04 lts system and i have followed the installation steps for docker.
I was trying to do same text on docker but it is throwing the error.
How to configure the docker engine with crun container runtime.
